# Automatically compute GEOGRAPHY polygon from inserted values in MemSQL

Tags: geospatial, singlestore

In MemSQL I can compute a `GEOGRAPHYPOINT` automatically from inserted values easily:

```
CREATE TABLE point_test (
  id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  lon DECIMAL,
  lat DECIMAL,
  point AS GEOGRAPHY_POINT(lon, lat) PERSISTED GEOGRAPHYPOINT,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

How would I do the same with a `GEOGRAPHY` polygon? I've tried several variations like

```
CREATE TABLE area_test (
  id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  lon1 DECIMAL,
  lon2 DECIMAL,
  lat1 DECIMAL,
  lat2 DECIMAL,
  area AS GEOGRAPHY_AREA("POLYGON((lon1 lat1, lon1 lat2, lon2 lat2, lon2 lat1, lon1 lat1))") PERSISTED GEOGRAPHY,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

but to no avail. I can see that the fields in the polygon are not expanded during insert, hence leading to a `NULL` area, but I can't seem to create a valid expression for `GEOGRAPHY_AREA` in the same manner as for `GEOGRAPHY_POINT`.

**EDIT:**
I was able to solve the issue with the hints provided by Joseph Victor. A `GEOGRAPHY` can effectively be computed on insert as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE area_test (
 id INTEGER NOT NULL,
 lon1 DECIMAL,
 lon2 DECIMAL,
 lat1 DECIMAL,
 lat2 DECIMAL,
 area AS CONCAT("POLYGON((", lon1," ",lat1,",",lon1," ",lat2,",",lon2," ",lat2,",",lon2," ",lat1,",",lon1," ",lat1,"))") PERSISTED GEOGRAPHY,
 PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, this kind of sucks, but the `lat1` things are in a string.
Also, GEOAGRAPHY_AREA returns a double, not a GEOGRAPHY.
Try

```
area AS GEOGRAPHY_AREA(CONCAT("POLYGON((",
                              lon1,
                              " ",
                              lon2,
                              ",",
 ...
                              ")")) PERSISTED DOUBLE
```

Comment: Oh, I see! I might have to correct my original question then... I'm trying to generate a `GEOGRAPHY` from the coordinates, not an area/surface (where a scalar/double makes perfect sense). Would a `GEOGRAPHY` field need a similar approach for the `POLYGON` parameters?

Comment: you need to use CONCAT, but remove the call to GEOGRAPHY_AREA, and do PERSISTED GEOGRAPHY.

Comment: Thank's a lot, it works! I'll gladly accept that as an answer.